# Missing values in plotting ggplot

Tags: r

I try to plot using

```
ggplot2
```

However I receive this error:

```
Error in ggproto(NULL, super, call = match.call(), aesthetics = aesthetics,  : 
  argument "values" is missing, with no default
```

Here the data of ploting

```
  IND1 <- c(3.422 -0.11708, -0.58419, NA, -2.40179, 0.26907, -2.30089, NA, NA)
   Dep <- c("D1","D2","D3","D4","D5","D6","D7","D8")
dd <- data.frame(Dep, IND1)   
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dd, aes(x = Dep, y = IND1, fill = (IND1 > 0))) +
    geom_col() +
    scale_fill_manual(value = c("purple", "blue")) +
    coord_flip()
I think it has to do with NA I have. Is there anything I can?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a typo:

replace

```
scale_fill_manual(value = c("purple", "blue"))
```

with

```
scale_fill_manual(values = c("purple", "blue"))
```